# casting unsigned char to char would result in different binary representations?

Tags: c, casting, char, unsigned, signed

I think the title is pretty self explanatory but basically what I'm saying is that, if I have the following instruction:

```
a = (char) b;
```

knowing that `a`'s type is `char` and `b`'s is `unsigned char`, can that instruction result in making `a` and `b` have different binary representations?

Comment: The title is anything but self-explanatory. It's barely explanatory.

Comment: @KerrekSB Ok, thanks for the edit, but can you help me or not? :)

Comment: I do not know whether it is well defined, but I thing it will not change the binary representation. Even if `char` is equal to `signed char` with your compiler.

Comment: Try this: `unsigned char b = 255; char a = (char) b; unsigned char c = (unsigned char) a; printf("%d %d %d\n", b, a, c);`

Comment: @Bob__ yep, that's what I thought because of the flag in the signed one. Thanks, that helped a lot!

Comment: @Bob__; Trying a single example doesn't prove anything. See Kerrek SB's answer.

Comment: @KeithThompson I know that the conversion from unrepresentable unsigned char value to char results in an implementation-defined result (and probably a bad idea), but I'm not aware of any actual implementation other then two's complement for binary signed number representation. Can you, please, give us a counter example?

Comment: @Bob__: I don't have an actual example. I know there have been 1's-complement implementations (and in principle there could be sign-and-magnitude implementations), but I don't recall the details. My statement is based on the guarantees made (or not made) by the standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer in general, is no, there is no difference. Here you can test it yourself. Just supply the respective values for 'a' and 'b'

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

const char *byte_to_binary(int x)
{
    static char b[9];
    b[0] = '\0';

    int z;
    for (z = 128; z > 0; z >>= 1)
        strcat(b, ((x & z) == z) ? "1" : "0");
    }

    return b;
}


int main(void) {
    unsigned char b = -7; 
    char a = -7; 
    printf("1. %s\n", byte_to_binary(a));
    a = (char) b;
    printf("2. %s\n", byte_to_binary(a));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've tried it and the binary value of `a` is always the same as the `b` one. What can, and will be different if the value is 255 is the decimal representation, right? In the signed char, 255 is represented as -1.

Comment: Signed chars are from -127 to 128. -1 is almost **always** an error return value. Only  unsigned are in the range 0 to 255.

Comment: Sorry this does not prove anything. The result is implementation defined and as a result it may just work for you but not necessarily all implementations.

Comment: Yes, as always with C, that's why I put *in general*.

Comment: This code doesn't examine the *representation* of either object at all. To do so, you would require some kind of "reinterpretation", such as `*(unsigned char*)(&a)`. This code just operates on values.

Comment: I used `static_cast` instead of `reinterpret_cast`, because this was specified by OP in `a = (char) b;`

Comment: The phrase "in general" can mean either "usually" or "always". And you're glossing over the fact that the result of the conversion is implementation-defined. [Kerrick SB's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34779196/827263) is correct.

Answer (score 4):

The type `char` can be either signed or unsigned. Char types have no padding, so all bits are value bits.

- If `char` is unsigned, then the value bits of `a` will be the same as those of `b`.
- If `char` is signed, then...

  - if the value of `b` is representable by `char`, the common value bits of `a` and `b` will the same.
  - otherwise, the conversion from unrepresentable `unsigned char` value to `char` results in an *implementation-defined* result.

Comment: Yes, I was aware that if the `char` was unsigned that would result in the same binary representation, my doubt was in what happens if it's signed, because that means it has less "room" since it has to have the flag.

Comment: Are you sure that `char` may not have padding bits?

Comment: @FUZxxl: C11, 6.2.6.2/1.

Comment: Starting with C99, the conversion can also raise an implementation-defined signal (though I don't know of any implementations that do this). C11 6.3.1.3p3